# Can someone explain why this function returns None?

Tags: python, arrays, list, function, set

I've been trying to figure out why this function is returning None every time I run it, I would appreciate a lot if someone could explain my why.

```
x = set([1,2,3])

def inserta(multiconjunto, elemento):
   
   a = multiconjunto.add(elemento)
   
   return a

mc1 = inserta(x, 2)
print(mc1)
```

Comment: How could I fix it?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do. Why are you trying to return a value from the function?

Comment: I'm trying to add a number to the set, but my teacher told me I have to write it as a function, directly it would be x.add(2)

Comment: I don't understand that, but a function doesn't have to return a value. You could just call it `inserta(x, 2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns none because `set.add()` returns `None`, the `add()` method modifies the set, it does not return a new set.

There's no reason to put such a simple operation inside your own function, but if you insist you could do this:

```py
x = set([1,2,3])

def inserta(multiconjunto, elemento):
   multiconjunto.add(elemento)

inserta(x, 2)
print(x)
```

if you want to return a new set for some reason then:

```py
x = set([1, 2, 3])


def inserta(multiconjunto, elemento):
    new_set = set(multiconjunto)
    new_set.add(elemento)

    return new_set


mc1 = inserta(x, 5)
print(mc1)
print(x)
```

should do the trick. It outputs

```
{1, 2, 3, 5}
{1, 2, 3}
```

Comment: Do you know how it could return the set with the added value?

Comment: It doesn't need to return the set because it's modified in place